# Pre-render Spline frame in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, 3d, lazy-loading, spline

I want to add a Spline frame to my application but it takes a while to load (I already optimized the 3D object). I was thinking of adding a loading page before accessing the home page where the spline frame is but this will only solve my solution only when accessing the website for the first time. Is there a way to preload the spline frame/component so that it stays loaded every time I access the respective page? Maybe get a stale version of it with no animations?